# String.slice! produces wierd result

Tags: mysql, ruby

The following produces a strange result for slice! (unless I have made a mistake).

irb session with ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-linux]

```
irb(main):001:0> a= File.read(',a');nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> a.class.name
=> "String"
irb(main):003:0> a.size
=> 66173
irb(main):004:0> b=a.slice(0..65534);nil
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> b.size
=> 65535
irb(main):006:0> a.slice!(0..65534);nil
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> a.size
=> 638
irb(main):008:0>
```

where file ",a" is a text string of length 66173 characters.

The string needs to be trimmed to fit a mysql column of type :text which has a max size of 65535 characters,

If the variable **a** is sliced to a new String variable **b** it results in a correct slice.

If the variable **a** is sliced in place, seems to do odd things resulting in a length of **638**. Why?

Could someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `slice!`
>
> Deletes the specified portion from str, and returns the portion deleted.

```
66173 - 65535
# => 638
```

tl;dr: `a = slice!(...)` is *not* equivalent to `a = a.slice(...)`.

Comment: more careful reading of the definition would have helped. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `slice!()` method modifies the string in place indeed, but has still a similar semantic.

```
a.slice!(0..65534);
```

will return and *delete* the 0..65534 part and a will have the remaining characters.